# PERL ; Match string from file; replace with comment

Tags: regex, xml, perl

file content example

```
cat File.txt
RHO_BID_RT
RHO_ASK_RT
```

XML FILE CONTENTS

```
    <field name="RHO_BID_RT" type="float" id="0x01D3" sequence="1"/>
    <field name="RHO_ASK_RT" type="float" id="0x01D4" sequence="1"/>
```

PERL CODE

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $re = join "|", map { chomp; quotemeta } `cat File.txt` }       s/<[^>]+  "field name="($re)"[^>]+>/<!! REMOVED $1 -->/g' fields.xml
```

Not sure why I am not getting intended results

```
<!-- Removed RHO_BID_RT-->
<!-- Removed RHO_ASK_RT-->
```

Comment: Could it be that you are using the wrong file name? In your one-liner you use `List.txt`, and in your question you say the name is `File.txt`.

Comment: Good observation but I edited the original question to match. This is not the issue.

Comment: You have a double quote before `field name` that is not there in the xml. Also, you have spaces before the field name, and using `+` quantifier, which requires at least one character that is not `>`.

Comment: It seems perverse to cram what should be a Perl script into a one-liner, especially when you need to process two input files separately. It results in code that is unnecessarily difficult to debug, as you have found with your 150-character monstrosity. In addition there is the usual admonition to *always* use a proper XML parser to process XML data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a double quote before `field name` that is not there in the xml. Also, you have spaces before the field name, and using `+` quantifier, which requires at least one character that is not `>`.

With the above stuff amended, the below one-liner works as intended. Note that this is Windows, so I have "translated" certain things.

```
perl -pwe"BEGIN { $re = join '|', map { chomp; quotemeta } qx(type file.txt); } s/<[^>]*field name=\x22($re)\x22[^>]+>/<!! REMOVED $1 -->/g" fields.xml
<!! REMOVED RHO_BID_RT -->
<!! REMOVED RHO_ASK_RT -->
```

Comment: Thank you very much TLP for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in a Perl program that uses [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) to parse the XML, and replaces with a comment all `field` elements having any of the given names, then this fits the bill.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use List::Util 'any';

my @names = do {
  local @ARGV = 'File.txt';
  map { chomp; $_; } <>;
};

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented', );
$twig->parsefile('fields.xml');

for my $field ( $twig->get_xpath('field') ) {
  my $name = $field->att('name');
  if ( any { $name eq $_ } @names ) {
    my $comment = XML::Twig::Elt->new('#COMMENT' => " Removed $name ");
    $comment->paste(after => $field);
    $field->cut;
  }
}

$twig->print;
```

When `File.txt` is as you have described and `fields.xml` contains this

```
<root>
  <field name="RHO_AAA_RT" type="float" id="0x01D1" sequence="1"/>
  <field name="RHO_BID_RT" type="float" id="0x01D2" sequence="1"/>
  <field name="RHO_ASK_RT" type="float" id="0x01D3" sequence="1"/>
  <field name="RHO_ZZZ_RT" type="float" id="0x01D4" sequence="1"/>
</root>
```

produces this output

```
<root>
  <field id="0x01D1" name="RHO_AAA_RT" sequence="1" type="float"/>
  <!-- Removed RHO_BID_RT -->
  <!-- Removed RHO_ASK_RT -->
  <field id="0x01D4" name="RHO_ZZZ_RT" sequence="1" type="float"/>
</root>
```

Comment: It's a false economy to reduce something like XML parsing to a one liner. This is the 'correct' way to do it.